# Making computation more efficient using a binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, binary, differential-equations

I am solving N coupled differential equations (u1(t),v1(t),u2(t),v2(t),...) iteratively. I have a ring of N oscillators, and each oscillator is connected to P neighbours. I am trying to improve the efficiency by not saving all of my iteration steps into lists, but instead by exporting my results for every 10th time step into a binary file which I later import so that I can plot the results over time. The following is my old code where I haven't used a binary file. The results are good, but it's inefficient:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt = 0.001
ts = np.arange(0, 30, dt)
N, P = 4, 2 

u = np.array([np.zeros(len(ts)) for i in range(N)]) 
v = np.array([np.zeros(len(ts)) for i in range(N)])

def a_u(j,t,P,u,v):
    del_li = []
    for k in range(j-P,j+P):
        del_li.append(u[k][t-1] - u[j][t-1])
    return (u[j][t-1] - ((u[j][t-1])**3)/3 - v[j][t-1] + (1/(4*P))*sum(del_li)) 

for t in range(len(ts)):
    for j in range(-P,P):  

        u[j][t] = u[j][t-1] + a_u(j,t,P,u,v)*dt
        v[j][t] = v[j][t-1] + (u[j][t-1] + 1.05)*dt + np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(dt))
```

My attempt to make the above code faster using a binary file looks as follows:

```
u, v = np.array(np.zeros(N)), np.array(np.zeros(N))   

def a_u(j,t,P,u,v):
    del_li = []
    for k in range(j-P,j+P):
        del_li.append(u[k] - u[j])
    return (u[j] - ((u[j])**3)/3 - v[j] + (1/(4*P))*sum(del_li)) 

with open('oscillators.bin', 'wb') as f: # write binary file
    for t in range(len(ts)):
        osc_list = []

        for j in range(-P,P): 

            u[j] += a_u(j,t,P,u,v)*dt  
            v[j] += (u[j] + 1.05)*dt + np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(dt))

            if not t % 10:  

                osc_list.append(u[j])
                osc_list.append(v[j])

                if j==P:
                    np.save(f, osc_list) 

fp = open("oscillators.bin", 'rb') # read binary file

a = []
for i in range(int(len(ts)/10)): 
    a.append(np.load(fp))

A = np.array(a) # u[1], v[1], ... = A[:,0], A[:,1], ...
```

Am I taking the correct steps to improve the efficiency of my code?  My real code is much more complicated than this, and the parameters that I am using are much larger, so efficiency is important.

Comment: How do you determine "wrong"? After all, you have a random input to your SDE. And of course the results will be different when you change the computation, you are mixing old and new values in the computation of `v[j]`.

Comment: With `j in range(-P,P+1)` you have computations for both `u[-P]` and `u[P]`, but they are the same array element.

Comment: A slight random variation isn't a problem. If I run the first code several times, the images all look similar. The problem is that when I run the second code the images look completely different.

Comment: Your code runs in under a second anyway, so I don't understand why you think it will be faster if you write binary files to disk every 10 steps.

Comment: My real code is much more complicated than this. Also N = 100, P = 50, t = 500. I have only used simple code and small numbers for purpose of asking the question

Comment: If speed is your concern, why don't you make full use of the power of the vectorization of numpy to reduce the number of explicit loops, why do you construct lists via `append`? What is the meaning of the index range using negative indices?

Comment: What images are you looking at, just the collection of graphs of `u`? And as the second computation is not the same as the first, one should expect different results.

Comment: I am looking at a ring of N oscillators. Each oscillator is connected with P neighbours on each side. That's why I loop from -P to P.

Comment: I've never used the power of vectorization of numpy before. How could I go about that?

Comment: It seems to me that the second computation is basically the same as the first. The coupled equations are the same in both, and in both I have solved the coupled equations using the same iterative method. I don't see why the images of one should be fundamentally different on average to the images of the other. I would like to look at the images u[1] over t, u[2] over t, ...., u[1] over v[1], u[2] over v[2], etc.

Comment: I have just read online "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance". I'm not sure if replacing vectorize with append would speed up my performance.

Comment: Ok, so defining N and P separately now makes sense. However, your equations do not have any coupling with neighboring nodes, they do not reflect that part of the description. Additionally, your example size is so small that you get wrap-around overlap. // Your quote is about the `vectorize` function wrapper. Using numpy array operations is faster than using explicit loops, that is the raison-d'être of the numpy package. Also, a block-wise call of the random-number generator is faster than the single calls for one random number each.

Comment: And no, the second computation is not the same as the first. As I said, first you have the wrap-around overlap at `u[2],v[2]` and then you are using the freshly computed `u[j]` value to compute `v[j]`, that is, you use `u[j][t]` instead of `u[j][t-1]`.

Comment: Oh you're right about the coupling with neighbourhood nodes. I simplified my code for the purposes of asking this question, but now I simplified too much. I've added the coupling now.

Answer (score 1):

In your second computation, in the first line, you are allocating the `u` and `v` arrays to the same memory location. That is, when you assign to `u[j]` and `v[j]`, you assign to the same place, overwriting the previous content. This will give a completely different computation.

Using loops in the way you do will only be efficient if you compile the code with cython or similar, where the usual overhead of the type-ambiguous python language gets reduced and you get the advantage of avoiding the allocation and garbage collection of the `u,v` arrays in every step. Else the numpy mechanism of vectorized operations

```
u,v = u - (u**3)/3 - v)*dt, (u + 1.05)*dt + np.random.normal(scale=np.sqrt(dt), size=len(v))
```

is faster. But still, this form does not present any coupling to neighboring nodes.

Comment: Aha! You're completely right about  u = v = np.array(np.zeros(N)) causing errors. I should have written u, v = np.array(np.zeros(N)), np.array(np.zeros(N)). When I do this the images with both methods look much more similar. There are still some significant differences between the two images. I think this is due to using u[j][t] instead of u[j][t-1] as you explained earlier.

Comment: Aha! I'd made a minor typing error. Now both images look about the same! Thank you very much! This still leaves open the question of efficiency. Given my coupling term, do you think I should be using loops with cython or similar, or is there another way?

Comment: You get now the problem that the index ´j+P-1` eventually exceeds the upper bound of the array, in the current form this could be solved by using the convolution operation (or `np.polymul`) with post-processing. If the coupling is later made non-linear, the implementation using array operations becomes more complicated.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you mean the 'k in range(j-P,j+P)'? If I exceed the last element of the array, don't I just arrive at the first element of the array? I don't see a problem with that, since all my oscillators are in a circle. How would I use the convolution operation?

Comment: Usually you should get an error, it is only the negative indices that automatically wrap around to the end. // I do not see a simple way, it is probably easier to code the rotation for each shift separately in a loop.

Comment: Oh yeah. When I run my code I don't get an error. I've been thinking, and it seems to me that my index j+P never exceeds the upper bound of my array since j+P <= P + P <= N. My arrays u and v have N elements.